# Does the conversation with Matriarch Aethyta go the same way if you haven't watched the video archives in the Shadow Broker base?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Unfortunately, I didn't realize that there were actually *3* sets of videos in the archives when I played through Lair of the Shadow Broker. By the time I knew, I'd already finished all of my sidequests, so I couldn't go and do a mission to trigger the 3rd set to show up. I ended up just importing my Shepard to Mass Effect 3 after having only watched 2 of the sets in the interest of time.

Now, during a conversation with Matriarch Aethyta,

> Shepard mentioned that she saw a video of her staring at a picture of Liara, which prompts Aethyta to admit her parentage. Do you still find out about Liara being Aethyta's daughter if you haven't seen this archive?

Essentially, I'm wondering if I may miss other triggers based off the set of videos I missed... Is Shepard's mentioning of the video merely an added bit of flavor if you've done the DLC, or is it a needed trigger in order to find this information out at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Mass Effect Wiki entry for [**Matriarch Aethyta**](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Matriarch_Aethyta) you merely need to complete the DLC for Shepard to mention this.

> If the player has completed Lair of the Shadow Broker, Shepard will directly mention the vid of Aethyta looking at the picture of Liara

---

My experience with this scene is that I do not even own the Broker DLC.  Importing that Shepard with this convo did not even mention the video, but she still revealed herself to be Liara's father, with Shepard having...an awkward time accepting a female as a 'father'.

Comment: First hand experience would be nice. This answer is currently the equivalent of "This other guy on the internet doesn't directly answer the question, but implies that yeah, probably she does". Not very authoritative.

Comment: I don't own the DLC at all and imported that Shepard and Shepard didn't mention anything about the vid but still revealed herself to be Liara's father.

Comment: Yeah! That's what I'm talking about! +1

Comment: \m/ ROCK ON!!!!

Comment: The information that Matriarch Aethyta gives during regular gameplay implies (or even informs) that she's the father of a pureblood.  A little deductive reasoning says that it's probably Liara that she fathered.

Comment: In mine she outright stated that she is Liara's father, I guess you just have to choose the right option.

Answer (score 0):

I've not played LOTSB, and yep, she admits it. And is all protective over her little girl, while Shepard squares up to her at one point, to show how protective s/he is too. It's quite funny.