# How do I get Matriarch Aethyta on the Presidium?

Tags: mass-effect-3

What do I need to do to get Matriarch Aethyta to show up on the Presidium? I do not see her there in my playthrough, and I don't know if that's because I haven't done something I need to, or I'm looking in the wrong area, or what.

I know you can see her, because of this question.

[Does the conversation with Matriarch Aethyta go the same way if you haven't watched the video archives in the Shadow Broker base?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54995/does-the-conversation-with-matriarch-aethyta-go-the-same-way-if-you-havent-watc)

Comment: How far in the game are you?  There is a certain point where she will not show up, I believe

Comment: Am fighting on Rannoch.

Comment: @TylerShads Is she there from the beginning?

Comment: @RavenDreamer Yes she was there

Comment: @TylerShads I'd make that the answer then. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

She was at the bar by where Liara sits from the beginning of the first time you can go to the Presidium.

I do not have anything official at the moment, but after the attack on the Citadel, a lot of NPCs change around.  It is possible that, she is one of these NPCs as I did have all the dialogue available before the attack.

I did not do the Shadow Broker DLC but I could still have some choices, including having Liara talk to her but she no longer appears in the Citadel after the attack.

Comment: Oh I see. I guess I justnever looked in the right place for her. Too busy helping out mah buddy Wrex. :D

Comment: I'm sad you don't get a Krogan squadmate =/ I miss Wrex/Grunt

Comment: Wrex. Shpeard. Wrex. Shepard. Wrex. Shepard.